# The positions of all vowels in the string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am trying to write programs that reads a line of input as a string and print the positions of all vowels in the string.

```
line = str(input("Enter a line of text: "))

vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
position = ""
for i in line :
    if i.lower() in vowels :
       position += ("%d ", i)
print("Positions of Vowels " + position)
```

Expected: `Positions of Vowels 1,3,4,5,`

Gives me: `Positions of Vowels`

What can I do?

Comment: Use `enumerate`. Also what is the input for your expected output?

Comment: What are you expecting `position += ("%d ", i)` to do? That isn't formatting a string

Comment: Input: We attend OCC.
Output: Positions of Vowels 1,3,6,10,

Comment: Instead of `"%d ", i` you want `"%d " % i`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a list of indexes, the following should work using `enumerate`:

```
>>> text = 'hello world vowel'
>>> vowels = 'aeiou'
>>> [i for i, c in enumerate(text.lower()) if c in vowels]
[1, 4, 7, 13, 15]
```

For your comma formatting:

```
>>> ', '.join(str(i) for i, c in enumerate(text.lower()) if c in vowels)
'1, 4, 7, 13, 15'
```

Comment: `code`pos = ""
for i, c in enumerate(line.lower()) :
    if c in vowels:
        pos += str(i)
print("Position of Vowels ", ','.join(pos))

Comment: Input: We attend OCC.

Output: Position of Vowels  1,3,6,1,0

Comment: What can I do to fix the output?

Comment: @Mark You are appending to a string and then joining, which will split each *digit* (`10` becomes `1,0`). If you don't want to use my list comprehension, just amend to `pos=[]` and `pos.append(str(i))` and it should work.